# phpunit stops at 100 assertions

Tags: xml, zend-framework, phpunit

I've been struggling for a while with phpunit and zend framework trying to be agile. I have a xml file with the config that had been working for a while

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php">
    <testsuite name="Unit test">
        <directory>./unit</directory>
    </testsuite>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../../library/Zend</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

See that's a simple config file. Now, when I reach the 100 assertions (yuppi!!) or is it the 10.00Mb Memory, I've found that the phpunit is not evaluating any more classes nor methods. I keep having this same output

```
PHPUnit 3.6.3 by Sebastian Bergmann.
Configuration read from C:\folder\tests\phpunit.xml
.............................
Time: 4 seconds, Memory: 10.00Mb
OK (29 tests, 100 assertions)
```

Am I missing something here? I've also tryed doing `testsuites` and `groups` but in the end I don't think that last is working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a phpunit test that outputs the current value for the memory limit `echo ini_get('memory_limit');`

If that is 10M, or close, edit it in php.ini (set to -1 to have no limit at all).

P.S. make sure you are looking at the right configuration file for the cli version of php.

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Config"
```

P.P.S. I'd not leave `memory_limit` at -1, once you confirmed that is the issue. I would set it to something much bigger, such as 64M. Then, in future, if a non-broken script ever needs more, increase it again.

Comment: @AlwinKesler Great. I just added a note to point out not to leave at -1. memory_limit can catch genuine problem scripts before they bring your system down :-)